# Plotting a Venn digram of many groups

Tags: r, intersection, venn-diagram

I have data from 12 classes:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(paste("a",1:1000,sep="."),
                      paste("b",1:2000,sep="."),
                      paste("c",1:100,sep="."),
                      paste("d",1:500,sep="."),
                      paste("e",1:200,sep="."),
                      paste("f",1:550,sep="."),
                      paste("g",1:2100,sep="."),
                      paste("h",1:900,sep="."),
                      paste("i",1:200,sep="."),
                      paste("j",1:3500,sep="."),
                      paste("k",1:4100,sep="."),
                      paste("l",1:2100,sep=".")),
                 class=c(rep("A",1000),
                         rep("B",2000),
                         rep("C",100),
                         rep("D",500),
                         rep("E",200),
                         rep("F",550),
                         rep("G",2100),
                         rep("H",900),
                         rep("I",200),
                         rep("J",3500),
                         rep("K",4100),
                         rep("L",2100)))
```

for which I want to plot a Venn diagram in `R`.

Using the `venneuler` `package`:

```
plot(venneuler(as.matrix(df)))
```

[image]

Kind of surprising since `df` has no overlaps between any of the classes.

Any idea if this can be avoided or of any other Venn diagram plotting `R` package that's able to handle such a large number of classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with [eulerr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=eulerr) (a package that I have developed), although it is incredibly slow given the large amount of possible set combinations.

```
vec <- as.vector(table(df$class))
names(vec) <- unique(df$class)
plot(eulerr::euler(vec))
```

[image]